# Seeking a resource to explain the Origins and rules governing words pronounced as if they contained an "R", but not spelled as such?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

There are words that, when pronounced with an British English accent, appear to contain the letter "R", but which are not written as containing one.

Bath and path, for example.

In contrast words like Hearth, and Dearth, which contain the same vowel + "TH" pattern, but also contain an "R".

Are there any available resources that can be used to explain the origins of this, how to properly teach where it applies, or to explain how a student might identify where this is the case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. This is a site for questions about techniques and hard-to-find resources for learning or teaching languages. Questions about how certain aspects of grammar or pronunciation work or how they originated are off topic here.

Comment: I asked for techniques to identify this part of grammar.

Comment: Take it to ell.se (English language learners).